# Is it possible to set a custom polling rate for USB input devices?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, refresh-rate

First time posting here.

I don't know very much about how polling rates work, but from what I've gathered I know they're hardware-based and cannot be directly modified.

So my question is this; Would it be possible to create a simple program that intercepts the input of a device (i.e. keyboard, mouse) and passes it through a sort of 'pseudo-polling rate' that only allows inputs to register on the refresh rate that you've set?

If possible, how could this be executed? Again, my knowledge is very limited on the topic but any info would be appreciated. For all I know this program already exists, so if anyone happens to know of something similar please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase USB polling rate across all devices in Linux - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/369826/increase-usb-polling-rate-across-all-devices-in-linux?rq=1)

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: Not only what is the goal, but what is the need?

Comment: And what operating system?